# Loading images from to differenet base resources to the webview

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I am implementing a WebView in which I need to use some images. For this, I use the images under the ressources folder and call

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:returnString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

It is working fine. In the same time I need to use some external images coming from the server in the same WebView. For this I need to change the baseURL of the target server but I don't know how to handle these two.

How to handle both images, from local and external server in one HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use full URLs (i.e. `http://www.exmaple.com/myimage.png`) for the images coming from the server, they won't be affected by the `baseURL` parameter, which is only used for resolving relative (partial) URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes we can do it as you suggested. But the total html is coming from the server I am just appending some images to that from  my local images for some use cases. So they doesn't provide full url. I have to make show the path by using baseURL.

Comment: Hey one more suggession I need. Is it possible to load local images into webview by using html with out pointing base url to Bundle?

Comment: @sek I think you're going to have to modify the image URLs within the HTML. You can either manipulate the HTML before you load, or call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` with some appropriate JS after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create two instance of `UIView` class and add the `UIWebView` in both the views.

In the first webview show the image from the resource and in the other webview show the image from the server.

Just give it a try see if this works.

Comment: Yes we can do it. But they won't scroll at a time. It creates a bad experience to the user